# get string array out of Dictionary<int, string[]>

Tags: c#

this is my code

```
pritvate static Dictionary<int, string[]> _list = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
```

how can i get the string[] out of this?
I have tried this and a lot more:

```
string[] s = _list.Values;
```

but it is all not working.

please help

Comment: Use the indexer `_list[someKey]`.

Comment: Provide a key value: `var key=7; string[] s = _list[key];`

Comment: This cannot work, because `_list.Values` is of a type similar to `string[][]`. Maybe you really want to have a `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: You should read documentation about dictionnary I think you did not understand the concept.

Comment: [Trial and error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error) isnt always the best approach, as @Nerevar already pointed out you should read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all string arrays for all keys merged into a single array, you can use LINQ's `.SelectMany(...)`:

```
var strings = _list.Values.SelectMany(v => v).ToArray()
```

---

Reading your question again, I wonder if you're asking how to access a value for a single key. So, if you want the string array for a single key you can simply use the indexer:

```
var value = _list["keyname"];
```

But that will cause an exception if the key doesn't exist. If you're not sure that the key exists, you can use `.TryGetValue(...)`:

```
string[] value;
if (_list.TryGetValue("keyname", out value))
{
    // value was found
}
else
{
    // value wasn't found
}
```